# As of 2018-06, is there an official gradle plug-in for AspectJ?

Tags: gradle, aspectj, gradle-plugin

As of 2018-06, is there an official gradle plug-in for AspectJ?

If so, where?

Comment: From [SO help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._ Having said that, a question back to you: How would you define "official"? And if there was anything "official", don't you think you would have found it on the AspectJ web site? Even AspectJ Maven is 3rd party and not maintained by the makers of AspectJ. Is that official?

Comment: @kriegaex You may consider my hand slapped.  “Official” to me means, ideally, “provided by the team that hosts AspectJ”.  Nonideally, it means “endorsed by the team that hosts AspectJ”.

Answer (score 0):

What is your objective exactly?

```
dependencies {
        classpath "nl.eveoh:gradle-aspectj:2.0"
    }

apply plugin: 'aspectj
```

[Gradle aspectj github repository](https://github.com/eveoh/gradle-aspectj)

Comment: Hopefully obviously, to weave advice and intertype declarations into classes at compile time.

Comment: Did you try above plugin?